# What is a dynamic framework as opposed to a non-dynamic one?

Tags: ios, xcode6

Xcode 6 allows for dynamic frameworks.

What is a *dynamic* framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both dynamic framework and static framework is a bundle containing a binary and some other things. The binary is called dynamic library or static library.

The binary is what you code is after compiling, your functions, classes, method become binary form, and they are called symbols.

**When building your project.**

Your code will be built into a binary, let's call it `MyProjectBinary`.
If your project links to a static library, then after building MyProjectBinary, linker check the symbols in `MyProjectBinary` and if it uses some part of the static library, for example, use a class in the static library), then linker will copy all the symbols related to the class and combine them in to `MyProjectBinary`. So no matter how many static library you use, you only get one building result, which is `MyProjectBinary`.

If you link to dynamic library, then you are telling the linker that, when `MyProjectBinary` is running, there will be that dynamic library at a suitable place. Dynamic library is not magic, in fact, you've used them for long time. All the frameworks Apple provides are dynamic libraries. They are guaranteed to exist when you app is running on device/simulator.

Let's assume that your project links to a dynamic library called `MyDynamicLibrary`. When building your project, first `MyProjectBinary` is still generated the same as using static library. Then, linker just add some information to `MyProjectBinary`, mark where to find "MyDynamicLibrary" at runtime. Nothing from `MyDynamicLibrary` will be add to `MyProjectBinary`

**When running your project:**

For the project using static library, nothing special happens, since all the code needed is inside `MyProjectBinary`, it just runs.

For the project using dynamic library, when your code calls a function which is in `MyDynamicLibrary`, the system tries to find `MyDynamicLibrary` according to the information stored in `MyProjectBinary`, if it finds `MyDynamicLibrary`, then for `MyProjectBinary`, the function is used like in `MyProjectBinary`. If it can't find `MyDynamicLibrary`, them an error will happen and you app will be terminated.

**So why do we need dynamic library for iOS 8?**

Before iOS8, an app can have only one executable binary, so using static library is OK.

But when iOS 8 comes, you can deliver multiple executable binary in one app, the additional binaries are extensions' executable binaries. This brings up a problem, if there are some code that are uses by multiple executable  binaries, and if using static library, same symbols will be copied into every executable, thus takes more space. This is the time when dynamic library comes in handy, we can put these code in dynamic library, and deliver only one copy of the dynamic library for app, the app and its extensions can use the same dynamic library.